# can't compile min_element in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class A {
  struct CompareMe {
    bool operator() (const string*& s1, const string*& s2) const { return true; }
  };
  void f() {
    CompareMe comp;
    vector<string*> v;
    min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
  }
};
```

And this is the error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(A::CompareMe) (std::string*&, std::string*&)’
test.cpp:7: note: candidates are: bool A::CompareMe::operator()(const 
std::string*&, const std::string*&) const
```

I feel that there is some syntax defect, but can't find out which one. Please, help!

Comment: Why do you have a vector of `string*`? `string*` is rarely ever what you want.

Comment: `string` is just for this example, in my real-life project it's not `string` but another class

Comment: A container of bare pointers is still prone to memory management bugs.

Comment: It's still unusual to have naked pointers in a container. If the container owns the object referenced by these pointers, it's going to be very hard to get the memory management right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your placement of `const` is wrong. [A `T*&` cannot be implicitly converted to a `const T*&`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17). Try

```
bool operator() (const string* const& s1, const string* const& s2) const { ...
//                             ^^^^^                    ^^^^^
```

instead.

---

Or just pass by value (thanks Mike):

```
bool operator() (const string* s1, const string* s2) const { ...
```

which will be more efficient for simple objects like a pointer, if the compiler uses a standard ABI.

Comment: Or pass the pointers by value, `bool operator()(const string*, const string*);`

Answer (score 2):

(This should be a comment, but a comment cannot be formatted thus, so it has to be an answer.)

The compiler's error message is very helpful. Just align what the compiler says it's expecting to what it says it's got:

```
(      std::string*&,       std::string*&)
(const std::string*&, const std::string*&)
```

Pretty obvious what's wrong, isn't it?